# Laravel blade: Unable to get id from object in url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i am working on eCommerce project where i got stuck with a issue. i am using url() to generate my url. i have a following code.

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" href='{{ url("search?category=$categories[$i]->id")}}' class="menuLinks leftCategoriesProduct"> <span class="catText">{{($categories[$i]->name)}}</span></a>
```

on click i require

> http://localhost/a2z/public/search?category=5

it worked on my one of the blade in the same project but here it generate a different url :

> http://localhost/a2z/public/search?category={%22id%22:5,%22name%22:%22All%20Offers%22,%22slug%22:%22all-offers%22,%22user_id%22:2,%22parent_id%22:null,%22deleted%22:0,%22created_at%22:%222017-04-10%2013:21:48%22,%22updated_at%22:%222017-04-10%2013:21:48%22,%22childs%22:[]}-%3Eid

Here it returns the whole object however i need only the category id

I am not sure where i am doing wrong, is there a concatenation problem, or something related to blade which i am missing.

Help will be appreciated, Thanx

Comment: please paste controller code

Comment: controller returning in a proper i  am just having problem here in concatenation as you can see in <a> its not having proper href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code:

```
{{ url('search') }}?category={{ $categories[$i]->id }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" href="{{ url('search', $categories[$i]->id) }}" class="menuLinks leftCategoriesProduct"> <span class="catText">{{($categories[$i]->name)}}</span></a>
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: it returns this url : http://localhost/a2z/public/search/5

wherever we require http://localhost/a2z/public/search?category=5

Comment: @ashutosh What is the route for search?

Comment: @ashutosh Please provide route for search

Answer (score 0):

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" href="{{ url('search?category='.$categories[$i]->id)}}" class="menuLinks leftCategoriesProduct"> <span class="catText">{{($categories[$i]->name)}}</span></a>
```